# bounded distributive lattice which is not pseudocomplemented

Tags: lattice-orders

Currently I'm studying lattice theory course using Lattice theory by gratzer...
I am stuck at the question that
"Give an example of bounded distributive lattice which is not pseudocomplemented"
I know that every finite distributive lattice is pseudocomplemented so that particular lattice must be infinite
Please answer

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Let $L$ be the lattice consisting of all finite subsets of $X$ along with one more set, namely the entire set $X$. This is a bounded distributive lattice. (The bounds are $\emptyset$ and $X$.)

$L$ is not pseudocomplemented, since, for $x\in X$, there is no largest finite subset of $X$ that is disjoint from $\{x\}$ and $X$ itself is not disjoint from $\{x\}$.

Comment: The largest element is not clear....can you elaborate please

Comment: The largest element is $X$. I edited the answer to emphasize that.

Comment: Thanks.......distributivity follows from elementary set theory and we get the answer......